# Onionbalance: Got the wrong number of responsible HSDirs: 5. Aborting

Tags: onion-services, load-balance

I have a hidden service with OnionBalancer. Service has been running for a long time but lately the OnionBalancer just stopped. From the logs:

```
[INFO]: Initialized hash ring of size 3906 (blinded key: b'Yi..CsE=')
[INFO]: Getting HS index with TP#19439 for first descriptor (1 replica)
[INFO]:          Tried with HS index 6bfc..78e9 got position 1649
[INFO]: Getting HS index with TP#19439 for first descriptor (2 replica)
[INFO]:          Tried with HS index 9c3c..e20e got position 2379
[INFO]:          HSDir set remained the same
[INFO]: No reason to publish first descriptor for abc..xyz.onion
[INFO]: We got 3 intros from 1 instances. We want 2 intros ourselves (got: 2)
[INFO]: Service abc..xyz.onion created second descriptor (2 intro points) (blinding param: 2121..e7ba) (size: 9783 bytes). About to publish:
[INFO]: Using srv 6aea..dca0 and TP#19440 (second descriptor)
[INFO]: Initialized hash ring of size 3906 (blinded key: b'4VF..qZI=')
[INFO]: Getting HS index with TP#19440 for second descriptor (1 replica)
[INFO]:          Tried with HS index fd109..8278 got position 3871
[INFO]: Getting HS index with TP#19440 for second descriptor (2 replica)
[INFO]:          Tried with HS index ffff..d040 got position 3906
[CRITICAL]: Got the wrong number of responsible HSDirs: 5. Aborting
[WARNING]: Can't publish desc with no hash ring. Delaying...
[INFO]: [*] fetch_instance_descriptors() called [*]
[INFO]: Initiating fetch of descriptors for all service instances.
[INFO]: Found instance rq2sx..eoiid for this new descriptor!
[INFO]: We got a new descriptor for instance rq2sx..eoiid but the intro set did not change.
[INFO]: [*] fetch_instance_descriptors() called [*]
[INFO]: Initiating fetch of descriptors for all service instances.
[INFO]: Found instance rq2sx..eoiid for this new descriptor!
[INFO]: We got a new descriptor for instance rq2sx..eoiid but the intro set did not change.
[INFO]: Signal 15 received, exiting
```

Server has the latest Tor installed but I haven't done any other changes. What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

0. **Back up your tor caches**!
1. Clear your Tor's caches and try to reconnect
2. If you'll still have this trouble - it looks like you're experiencing your SSL censorship/IP-blocking incident. In this case restore your Tor caches and make some collateral ways for your connections for directories

Feel free to drop me a line if it's not working - we'll fix it!